# Oracle VirtualBox mouse cursor help

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, mouse, cursor, guest-additions

I know this question has been asked before but none of the answers have helped.

Im having an issue where my cursor disappears behind my guest virtual machine screen and not being captured.

Im running Ubuntu as a virtual machine on a windows 7 laptop.
Guest additions is inserted and mouse integration is enabled.

This has been working up until today where the last thing i remember clicking on before or changing was selecting "seamless mode". I have since switched this back and that is when the cursor began playing up.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do i get the cursor back and operating as expected

Answer (score 0):

Pressing the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key on your keyboard should give you back mouse control.

Comment: Hi Lewis, thank you for your input, unfortunately this didnt work for me. In the end i just reinstalled the ubuntu iso